# Populate dict values based off relation to pandas column values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, geojson

Say I have a df with a name, lon, lat and place name. If I have a dictionary which will update those values iteratively, based on the name in the `df['name']` column, what would be the most efficient way to do that?

```py
#Example df:
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['jeff', 'susan','bill','emily'],
'lon':['25.0','43.9','18.8','22.4'],'lat':['19.3','11.2','45.3','28.0'],
'place':['Florida','Maine','Arizona','Colorado']})
```

gives:

```py
    name   lon   lat     place
0   jeff  25.0  19.3   Florida
1  susan  43.9  11.2     Maine
2   bill  18.8  45.3   Arizona
3  emily  22.4  28.0  Colorado
```

```py
geodict = {
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [df.lon, df.lat]
  },
  "properties": {
    "place_name": df.place
  }
}
```

I want to fill the dictionary so that the coordinates in the `df['lon']` and `df['lat']` and `df['place']` columns populate it based on the name in the column.

I am grabbing data based on the entries in `df['name']` and based on whichever name I'm looking up at the time.

```py
names = df['name'].values.tolist()

for n in range(len(names)):
<do some stuff>
    if names[n] in df['name'].values:
        <not sure what to do after this..., probably some k,v in geodict thing?>
```

I would like said dictionary to update with the df data, as per below. The end goal is to send to a geoJSON.

My final output I would like to look like this:

```py
geodict = {
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": ['25.0', '19.3']
  },
  "properties": {
    "place_name": 'Florida'
  }
}
#and so on for each entry.
```

There is other data meant to be added to the dictionary with `.update` but I am trying to keep this fairly brief, and it's not reliant on the df data or the geometric data in the dictionary.

Comment: "based on whichever name I'm looking up at the time." - Are you getting input `name` dynamically? One "name" at a time?

Comment: Did you wanted a `list` of `dict`s based on each `df['name']`?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes, I'm looping for `name[n]` in `names` (a list from `df['name']`).

@r.ook I want to fill in the `"coordinates"` and `"place_name"` key:values from the name in each iteration. so if I am searching with "jeff", it should fill out the `geodict` as per the example. and when I move to "susan" i should fill in those dict values with her information, and so on.

Comment: Is `geodict` already an existing dictionary and you are just updating the values? Or are you creating it? If you are updating, are you updating all the values at once or will only need to do a handful at a time?

Comment: it's already existing and I was intending for it to be updated each iteration of the parent for loop (it's sent to an output file at the end of the loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `to_dict()` method of `DataFrame` and then creating your `geodict` based on the results:

```
geodicts = {
  name: {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [vals.get('lon'), vals.get('lat')]
          },
      "properties": {
          "place_name": vals.get('place')
          }
        } for name, vals in df.set_index('name').T.to_dict().items()
    }
```

Output:

```
pprint(geodicts)
{'bill': {'geometry': {'coordinates': ['18.8', '45.3'], 'type': 'Point'},
          'properties': {'place_name': 'Arizona'},
          'type': 'Feature'},
 'emily': {'geometry': {'coordinates': ['22.4', '28.0'], 'type': 'Point'},
           'properties': {'place_name': 'Colorado'},
           'type': 'Feature'},
 'jeff': {'geometry': {'coordinates': ['25.0', '19.3'], 'type': 'Point'},
          'properties': {'place_name': 'Florida'},
          'type': 'Feature'},
 'susan': {'geometry': {'coordinates': ['43.9', '11.2'], 'type': 'Point'},
           'properties': {'place_name': 'Maine'},
           'type': 'Feature'}}
```

If you just needed them one by one instead:

```
def get_geodict(name):
    item = df.set_index('name').loc[name]
    geodict = {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [item.lon, item.lat]
      },
      "properties": {
        "place_name": item.place
      }
    }
    return geodict
```

Usage:

```
>>> get_geodict('jeff')
{'geometry': {'coordinates': ['25.0', '19.3'], 'type': 'Point'},
      'properties': {'place_name': 'Florida'},
      'type': 'Feature'},
```

And if you already have `geodict` and just want to update it:

```
def update_geodict(geodict, name):
    item = df.set_default('name').loc[name]
    geodict.setdefault('geometry', {}).update({'coordinates': [item.lon, item.lat]})
    geodict.setdefault('properties', {}).update({'place_name': item.place})
    return geodict
```

Usage:

```
>>> geodict = {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point"
      }
    }
>>> update_geodict(geodict, 'jeff')
{'geometry': {'coordinates': ['25.0', '19.3'], 'type': 'Point'},
      'properties': {'place_name': 'Florida'},
      'type': 'Feature'},
```

Answer (score 2):

Straightforwardly:

```
In [306]: input_name = 'bill'                                                                                                

In [307]: row = df[df['name'] == input_name].iloc[0]                                                                         

In [308]: geodict = {"type": "Feature",   
     ...:            "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [row.lon, row.lat]},  
     ...:            "properties": {"place_name": row.place}  
     ...: }  
     ...: print(geodict)                                                                                                     
{'type': 'Feature', 'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': ['18.8', '45.3']}, 'properties': {'place_name': 'Arizona'}}
```

In case you need *"geodict"* generation to be reusable - wrap the above approach into a function.